# How to use Bearer Token on Git repository

Tags: jenkins, testing, rest-assured, bearer-token

In my API testing automation framework, I'm using Bearer Token to validate the API. This token is in properties file. I cannot commit this property file on github as it contains api token. Can someone suggest how to use this API token when api testing framework will be invoked from jenkins it will take this git repo so how it will take the api access token(Bearer)?
How can I use api Bearer Token securely on github?

Answer (score 0):

In your repository, you can store data as [secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets), so they are not exposed to anyone by just viewing the repository.

Then you can use these secrets in a pipeline, for example as environment variables:

```
steps:
  - name: Hello world
    env:
      super_secret: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
```

So you code has to be able to work with environment variables.

Comment: okay. Thank you for the reply. I will check and update